# respond.js not working in IE8 with Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, respond.js

It seems like I did something wrong, because respond.js isn't working in IE8. I've placed html5shiv and respond.js as last element into my head, but it is just not loading. I don't get any errors, and the page is valid HTML. Anyone can point me to the problem:
http://hypnosewien.at/responsive/

Here is my head:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hypnose Wien</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="css/core.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Both files exist. I also tried to pull jquery up before those two scripts. Still not working.

Comment: The path to the css, all the css, has to be local or use a proxy, read the docs in full under the IE8 section. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: Thanks so much. That did the trick. If you could add this as an answer I can accept it immediately :)